# Using only two colors in a ListPlot3D

Tags: plotting

The data I have given here will plot the data in `ListPlot3D` function and gives the visualization of bars on the plot.

I want to customize the color for the bars in the plot. I need to plot them in two colors — one for side of the bar and another for the top surface of the bar. How can I set the color function to achieve this?

```
finalData = {{14.38, 18.1, 70}, {14.385714285714286`, 54.`, 
70}, {42.857142857142854`, 18.1`, 70}, {42.857142857142854`, 54.`,
 70}, {14.385714285714286`, 54.1`, 20}, {14.385714285714286`, 
90.`, 20}, {42.857142857142854`, 54.1`, 20}, {42.857142857142854`,
 90.`, 20}, {14.385714285714286`, 90.1`, 
15}, {14.385714285714286`, 126.`, 15}, {42.857142857142854`, 
90.1`, 15}, {42.857142857142854`, 126.`, 
15}, {14.385714285714286`, 126.1`, 25}, {14.385714285714286`, 
162.`, 25}, {42.857142857142854`, 126.1`, 
25}, {42.857142857142854`, 162.`, 25}, {14.385714285714286`, 
162.1`, 30}, {14.385714285714286`, 180, 30}, {42.857142857142854`,
 162.1`, 30}, {42.857142857142854`, 180, 
30}, {42.957142857142856`, 18.1`, 14}, {42.957142857142856`, 54.`,
 14}, {71.42857142857143`, 18.1`, 14}, {71.42857142857143`, 54.`, 
14}, {42.957142857142856`, 54.1`, 60}, {42.957142857142856`, 90.`,
 60}, {71.42857142857143`, 54.1`, 60}, {71.42857142857143`, 90.`, 
60}, {42.957142857142856`, 90.1`, 14}, {42.957142857142856`, 
126.`, 14}, {71.42857142857143`, 90.1`, 14}, {71.42857142857143`, 
126.`, 14}, {42.957142857142856`, 126.1`, 
24}, {42.957142857142856`, 162.`, 24}, {71.42857142857143`, 
126.1`, 24}, {71.42857142857143`, 162.`, 
24}, {42.957142857142856`, 162.1`, 34}, {42.957142857142856`, 180,
 34}, {71.42857142857143`, 162.1`, 34}, {71.42857142857143`, 180, 
34}, {71.52857142857142`, 18.1`, 18}, {71.52857142857142`, 54.`, 
18}, {100.`, 18.1`, 18}, {100.`, 54.`, 18}, {71.52857142857142`, 
54.1`, 28}, {71.52857142857142`, 90.`, 28}, {100.`, 54.1`, 
28}, {100.`, 90.`, 28}, {71.52857142857142`, 90.1`, 
23}, {71.52857142857142`, 126.`, 23}, {100.`, 90.1`, 23}, {100.`, 
126.`, 23}, {71.52857142857142`, 126.1`, 33}, {71.52857142857142`,
 162.`, 33}, {100.`, 126.1`, 33}, {100.`, 162.`, 
33}, {71.52857142857142`, 162.1`, 38}, {71.52857142857142`, 180, 
38}, {100.`, 162.1`, 38}, {100.`, 180, 38}, {100.1`, 18.1`, 
12}, {100.1`, 54.`, 12}, {128.57142857142858`, 18.1`, 
12}, {128.57142857142858`, 54.`, 12}, {100.1`, 54.1`, 
22}, {100.1`, 90.`, 22}, {128.57142857142858`, 54.1`, 
22}, {128.57142857142858`, 90.`, 22}, {100.1`, 90.1`, 
17}, {100.1`, 126.`, 17}, {128.57142857142858`, 90.1`, 
17}, {128.57142857142858`, 126.`, 17}, {100.1`, 126.1`, 
27}, {100.1`, 162.`, 27}, {128.57142857142858`, 126.1`, 
27}, {128.57142857142858`, 162.`, 27}, {100.1`, 162.1`, 
32}, {100.1`, 180, 32}, {128.57142857142858`, 162.1`, 
32}, {128.57142857142858`, 180, 32}, {128.67142857142858`, 18.1`, 
16}, {128.67142857142858`, 54.`, 16}, {157.14285714285714`, 18.1`,
 16}, {157.14285714285714`, 54.`, 16}, {128.67142857142858`, 
54.1`, 26}, {128.67142857142858`, 90.`, 26}, {157.14285714285714`,
 54.1`, 26}, {157.14285714285714`, 90.`, 
26}, {128.67142857142858`, 90.1`, 21}, {128.67142857142858`, 
126.`, 21}, {157.14285714285714`, 90.1`, 
21}, {157.14285714285714`, 126.`, 21}, {128.67142857142858`, 
126.1`, 31}, {128.67142857142858`, 162.`, 
31}, {157.14285714285714`, 126.1`, 31}, {157.14285714285714`, 
162.`, 31}, {128.67142857142858`, 162.1`, 
36}, {128.67142857142858`, 180, 36}, {157.14285714285714`, 162.1`,
 36}, {157.14285714285714`, 180, 36}, {157.24285714285713`, 18.1`,
 20}, {157.24285714285713`, 54.`, 20}, {185.71428571428572`, 
18.1`, 20}, {185.71428571428572`, 54.`, 20}, {157.24285714285713`,
 54.1`, 90}, {157.24285714285713`, 90.`, 
90}, {185.71428571428572`, 54.1`, 90}, {185.71428571428572`, 90.`,
 90}, {157.24285714285713`, 90.1`, 25}, {157.24285714285713`, 
126.`, 25}, {185.71428571428572`, 90.1`, 
25}, {185.71428571428572`, 126.`, 25}, {157.24285714285713`, 
126.1`, 35}, {157.24285714285713`, 162.`, 
35}, {185.71428571428572`, 126.1`, 35}, {185.71428571428572`, 
162.`, 35}, {157.24285714285713`, 162.1`, 
40}, {157.24285714285713`, 180, 40}, {185.71428571428572`, 162.1`,
 40}, {185.71428571428572`, 180, 40}};
ListPlot3D[finalData, Filling -> Bottom, RotationAction -> "Clip",AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}, {0, 100}}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListPlot3D[finalData, Filling -> Bottom, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}, {0, 100}}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> None, FillingStyle -> Black, 
 PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Comment: If you notice in my given plot there is gap between 0 and 18 along x and y axis. As per your idea when i put `InterPolationOrder-> 0` the gap between 0 and 18 is been filled, but i don't want the plot in that way. If i use `PlotRange` from 18 to 200 instead of 0 to 200, i can overcome this problem, but i don't want this way also.

Comment: @niren `ListPlot3D[finalData, Filling -> Bottom, RotationAction -> "Clip", 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}, {0, 100}}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> None, FillingStyle -> Black, 
 PlotStyle -> Red, RegionFunction -> (#1 > 18 && #2 > 18 &)]`

Comment: i tried the code you send but i don't the value 18 in my case. Then how do i mention 18 in regionfunction.